# SQL join two tables respecting order

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have got two tables. Table1 stores the position order of the codes. Table2 stores information of each code. I'm trying to do a query which done a id, returns the order of each code and its associated information.

```
TABLE1
+-------+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| id    | position1 | positon2 | position3 | position4 | position5 |
+-------+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| id1   | AA        | CC       | BB        | EE        | DD        |
|-------|-----------|----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| id2   | BB        | AA       | DD        | EE        | CC        |
+-------+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+

TABLE2
+------+------------+--------------------+
| code | name       | active_icon        | 
+------+------------+--------------------+
| AA   | nameA      | iconA              |
| BB   | nameB      | iconB              |
| CC   | nameC      | iconC              |
| DD   | nameD      | iconD              |
| EE   | nameE      | iconE              |
+------+------------+--------------------+
```

Done an id (for example id = id2), the result I'm expecting is:

```
+----------------+------+------------+--------------------+
| position       | code | name       | active_icon        |
+----------------+------+------------+--------------------+
|              1 | BB   | nameB      | iconB              |
|              2 | AA   | nameA      | iconA              |
|              3 | DD   | nameD      | iconD              |
|              4 | EE   | nameE      | iconE              |
|              5 | CC   | nameC      | iconC              |
+----------------+------+------------+--------------------+
```

Any ideas? I think there must be an INNER JOIN but I don't know how to structure it.

Comment: it would be better if you normalized Table 1.

Comment: With your Table 1 its hardly possible

Comment: Design your table properly.  Things that are supposed to have an easy solution will be complicated if your table structure is messed up.  For example, this...

Answer (score 0):

This is a denormalized design.  It'd be MUCH easier if you'd model it properly.  It'd be far more extensible, too.

I'd give table 1 a column for position and a foreign key to table 2 for the code.  You could have as many codes as you wished then.  Reordering would mean changing position values.  The JOIN writes itself then: just add an ORDER BY position.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT position, t1.code, name, active_icon
FROM (SELECT 1 AS position, id, position1 AS code
      FROM Table1
      UNION
      SELECT 2 AS position, id, position2 AS code
      FROM Table1
      UNION
      SELECT 3 AS position, id, position3 AS code
      FROM Table1
      UNION
      SELECT 4 AS position, id, position4 AS code
      FROM Table1
      UNION
      SELECT 5 AS position, id, position5 AS code
      FROM Table1) AS t1
JOIN Table2 AS t2
ON t1.code = t2.code
WHERE t1.id = :ID
ORDER BY position
```

Comment: While I'm sure it works, I hope we're not seriously advocating this as a solution. :-(

Comment: I wrote a comment recommending that he normalize his database. But that's not an answer, so I didn't put it here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use a [PIVOT](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/en/book_operator_pivot_unpivot.html) operation. But in MySQL pivot is unimpemented, but you can emulate it manually. See [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table) for examples.